# Clearing Out MySQL Grants on Startup Before Granting Again

Tags: mysql, database

i want to set up my code to clear out all of the grants for 'user' on startup and then grant them fresh privileges, kind of like this.

***REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* FROM 'user';***

***GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON db.* TO 'user';***

However, I'm getting the following error :

***SQL Error [1141][42000]: There is no such grant defined for user 'user' on host '%'***

Is there some sort of functionality where I can revoke privileges from a user if and only if they exist?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't.  The easy, faintly ridiculous way to work around it would be

```
GRANT SELECT ON db.* TO 'user';
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* FROM 'user';
GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON db.* TO 'user';
```

Comment: Well that's ridiculous, but I appreciate your response. Thank you.